# Using hexadecimal color code in System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, color-scheme

Is there a way to specify the hexadecimal code(something like #E9E9E9) while setting the color of a datagrid instead of using the below code.

```
dg.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
```

Comment: Please mark the correct answer to Answer, so that any other persons can help find answer to this question easily.

Comment: Thank you. How do I make the forecolor font bold in this same context?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
dg.BackColor =  System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E9E9E9");
```

Comment: Also take a look at the other functions from [ColorTranslator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzwa1ke2.aspx) to translate Ole colors or doing the transform vice versa (from `Color` to html string).

Comment: You should really take a look into the code of `FromHtml` with reflector. I like this special handling of *LightGrey* ;-)

Comment: Thanks you all,, how can I make the font bold using System.Drawing.Color for any color?

Comment: @Pooja, open up a new question for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
dg.BackColor = Sytem.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 0xE9, 0xE9, 0xE9);
```

or

```
string myColor = "#E9E9E9";
dg.BackColor = Sytem.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(myColor.Replace("#", "0x"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx):

```
dg.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xE9, 0xE9, 0xE9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Close:

```
Color.FromArgb(0, 0xe9, 0xe9, 0xe9);
```